# How can I keep track of anonymous users?

Tags: 7, users

I'm developing a module based on commerce that keeps track of certain user product selections by writing them to a database table. To keep track of who selected what I use the user id for registered users and the session id for unregistered ones. Or at least I would if it weren't for the fact that Drupal keeps changing the session id for every request.

Why is it doing that and how do I make it stop? Or is there a Drupal way of tracking anonymous users that does not involve `session_id()`?

Comment: take a look here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/123928/28275

Comment: Ah, that fixed it. Who decides to disable sessions.... Anyway, I don't remember stackexchange ettiquette on this, maybe you should copy that answer here so I can set it as accepted? On that question it's kind of a side note. I know I missed it the first time.